# Grammar Correction Required

Tags: phrase-meaning

Our company car is in the workshop, so I would like to ask my manager that who will collect; Also before he replies that you can collect by yourself, I want to tel him that in some cases even I can collect, so is it ok to ask as below;

> Please tell me who will collect the car from workshop?
>   In some cases even I can collect …

Regards

Comment: By "collect", do you mean to *get* or to *pay for*? "collect" would not be used this way in AmE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first sentence is almost correct. You just need to say "*the* workshop". Also, "please tell me" is an imperative, not a question, so the sentence is declarative:

> Please tell me who will collect the car from the workshop.

You could also make it a question:

> Who will collect the car from the workshop?

As for your second sentence, I would avoid "in some cases" to say that you might be able to collect the car yourself. It implies that you are about to lay out every case in which you would be able to do so: "If it's a Tuesday after 6pm, or a Wednesday before 4pm, or a Saturday that's also an odd-numbered day, I can collect the car." That's probably not what you're planning to say, and it wouldn't even be required. But "in some cases" implies to me that we're going to talk about what those cases are.

Instead, I would probably just say:

> I might be able to collect the car myself, depending on the [time | circumstances | day | your choice].

This says that you are volunteering to be on the list of people who can go and collect the car, but there's a chance you will need someone else to do it.